# Bonding/Teaming in centOS 7

Tags: linux, load-balancer, centos-7

I am new to linux. I have been trying to configure either NIC bonding or NIC teaming. I have done it on windows server 2012. I am using centos7 and I haven't been lucky enough to configure it correctly. 
The Lab that I am working in right now has 3 WANs that I plan to combine to act as one with link aggregation (Adaptive transmit load balancing). I have tried every way possible in my knowledge using the Network Manager, doing it manually, and by following the documentations as well. Please advice me the best way to do it. Also I haven't been able to find any documentation on Teaming in centos 7. I have have three interfaces that I will be using as WAN and the forth one as LAN. WAN interfaces will have manual IP setting... In all the examples that I saw none had any example with static ips on there slaves. Also my /etc/modprob.d/ is missing modeprob.conf. So all this concludes to following questions:

1. Where can I find the manual or manpages for Teaming.
2. Is is possible to use Static ips on slaves with bonding or teaming.
3. What is the best mode to use?
4. Is what I want achievable through CentOS?

Comment: Did you already look at bonding documentation for rhel7/centos7: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Configure_Network_Bonding.html